# import pandas in Python3.6 Idle fail after pip install

Tags: python, pandas

My system is Windows 10 Home version 1703.
I open a CMD (admin) terminal.
I type at the prompt: pip install -v.  It completes successfully.
I am using python 3.6.0.  In the python folder, from IDLE:

> > > import pandas
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >          File "", line 1, in 
> > >          File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\sie-packages\pandas__init__.py", line 19, in  
> > >             "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(mising_dependencies))
> > >       ImportEror:  Missing required dependencies ['numby']

Sorry, I tried to copy and paste to here but not successful, so I manually typed what I saw on my CMD screen.

Please advise.  I tried to look at the **init**.py but I don't know how it resolve the "dependencies" pointed in the error message I see above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you lack the `numpy` package which is used by `pandas`. Try install it with :

```
pip install numpy
```

If it doesn't work maybe uninstall and reinstall numpy and pandas.

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip uninstall pandas
pip install numpy
pip install pandas
```